# Excel add-in macros not showing up

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I've made an xlam to save all my editing macros as an add-in. However when I press alt f8 I do not see the add-in macros.
[Macro's not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mlQO.png)

I've also confirmed that sheets with the add-in installed do have the add-in show up in the add-in tab, and also as a VB project when I press alt-f11.
[VB editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7EER.png) [Add-in list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOnfm.png)
I also have the file location where the xlam saved as a trusted source.
[Trust center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAc9d.png)[Trust center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppyUm.png)

Comment: Only Subs that have no arguments will show up in the "Run Macro" dialog because you can't just run them without an argument.

Comment: ... and if they are Subs without arguments, they won't show either. If you want them to show, put them into the `PERSONAL.xlsb` and make sure they're not private. The functions will appear in the `Insert Function` box though if they're not private.

Comment: please show images in your text rather than a link